# Can't access /transmission

Tags: centos, services, bittorrent, transmission

I have installed Transmission service on Centos. It is running. The problem is when I type `myservername/transmission` in my browser address it doesn't open. It was working before.

Comment: When you say it was working before, what changed? What was the before/after condition? Did you check your options under transmission to see if the web service is still enabled?

Answer (score 3):

Open transmission. Go to Preferences and select Web tab and check the transmission web client settings.

- Check web client is enabled
- Check the listening port

You need a port to connect to the web client for example `http://localhost:9091`

**Edit**

Transmission-daemon (Commandline)
Open /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json and change the settings accordingly. Specially below values.

```
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1",
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,
```

Comment: How can I do these using terminal?

Comment: Are you using the command line version.(`transmission-daemon`). If you are using GUI version type `transmission` on terminal and follow my instructions.

Comment: I'm using command line version

Comment: white list is enabled and my IP is in white list.